# How to properly store strtok

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, realloc

I have:

```
while (token != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(NULL," ");
    array.var = realloc(array.var,(counter + 1) * sizeof(char *)); 
    array.var[counter] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);         
    strcpy(array.var[counter],token);
    counter++;
}
```

Where var is a variable in a struct declared as `char **var;`
When I try this, I get a seg fault and im not sure why. If take out the malloc and strcpy, it wont seg fault, but I need to store the token in the array. array is declared by myStruct array;

Comment: I told you to check that `malloc()` didn't return `NULL`, because that would lead to undefined behavior, and it's really bad practice to ignore the possible error codes or error values returned by functions, that aside, your code as is should work. Why are you sure that the SEGMENTATION FAULT is happening in this snippet? And also, `x = realloc(x, newSize);` is very bad, because if `realloc()` returns `NULL` you loose reference to the valid pointer that `x` pointed to.

Comment: I think its happening there because the program works fine if I don't include the realloc,malloc,strcpy. I'll add the error check, but im pretty sure it is NULL, thats why its seg faulting

Comment: What is `NULL`? Also, it might be what you do after filling the array of pointers.

Comment: why didn't you use the code I posted in my answer in your other post? that would have saved you and I and [Jammerx2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1794305/jammerx2) a lot of time, now you should pick hes answer, it's correct.

Comment: the return code from realloc() needs to be checked before assigning it to array.var.  because if realloc fails, then the original array.var memory pointer will be lost, resulting in a memory leak.  Any failure of malloc or realloc in this loop that is not detected in the code will result in accessing memory off address 0 which will result in a seg fault event.

Comment: the first call to strtok() must contain the address of the string being parsed as the first parameter.  then all following calls must contain NULL as the first parameter.  Perhaps that detail was handled before the posted code, but we cannot be sure.

Comment: this line: 'array.var[counter] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);' will cause a seg fault event when token is NULL because strlen will be trying to read offsets from address 0.  Should the execution get past the above line, (not likely),  then this line: 'strcpy(array.var[counter],token);' will cause a seg fault event because strcpy is trying read from offsets off address 0

Comment: This is what debuggers are for...

Answer (score 2):

You're checking if token is `NULL` before you get the next token with `strtok()`. The last call to strtok will be `NULL` and then `strlen(token)` will essentially be `strlen(NULL)` and cause a segfault. Change the code to assign the token at the end of the loop instead of the beginning, that will also stop you from skipping the first token.

```
while (token != NULL)
{
    array.var = realloc(array.var,(counter + 1) * sizeof(char *)); 
    array.var[counter] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);         
    strcpy(array.var[counter],token);
    counter++;
    token = strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

Comment: No, the check is performed in the right place. And `strlen(NULL)` will cause undefined behavior, not a SEGMENTATION FAULT.

Comment: strtok will return NULL when no more tokens are found. He assigns token at the beginning of the while loop and then proceeds to use it in both strlen and strcpy without checking if it's null.

Comment: Did I say it wouldn't? Unless the OP is not calling `strtok()` before entering the `while` loop, which is very unlikely, there is no way to dereference a `NULL` pointer in this code.

Comment: The first line of the while statement will make token `NULL`. After that he calls `strlen()` and `strcpy()` with token as an argument.

Comment: Is there any way to put the token=strtok(NULL," "); before the strcpy? The strcpy is also copying the token that was before it as well

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
token = strtok(NULL," ");
```

fails to check the result of the call to strtok()

suggest:

```
if( NULL == (token = strtok(NULL, " ") ) )
{// then, strtok failed to find a ' ' delimeter
   break;  // exit while loop
}

// implied else, strtok successful
```